# Quartz.net scheduler database noise query

Tags: quartz-scheduler

All,

We have a configured a Quartz.net scheduler. Its configuration is as follows:

```
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="Some_Id" />
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="Some_Name" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Some_ConString" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
```

When profiling the database, we noticed the following traffic executing every 23-27 seconds:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PRIORITY FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = ''Some_Name'' AND TRIGGER_STATE = @state AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME <= @noLaterThan AND (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1 OR (MISFIRE_INSTR <> -1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME >= @noEarlierThan)) ORDER BY NEXT_FIRE_TIME ASC, PRIORITY DESC',N'@state nvarchar(7),@noLaterThan bigint,@noEarlierThan bigint',@state=N'WAITING',@noLaterThan=635374746823951132,@noEarlierThan=635374745923951132
```

The following traffic executes every minute:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(TRIGGER_NAME) FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = ''Some_Name'' AND MISFIRE_INSTR <> -1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME < @nextFireTime AND TRIGGER_STATE = @state1',N'@nextFireTime bigint,@state1 nvarchar(7)',@nextFireTime=635374746017864938,@state1=N'WAITING'
```

Can anyone explain what this polling checks for?
Are these default settings as we have no configuration in place to scan for updates in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement is quartz server polling the database for triggers that are due to be fired and are not subject to any [misfire policies](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html)

Re: the second statement, here is the method comment straight from the [Quartz.net source code](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet):

```
            // Before we make the potentially expensive call to acquire the 
            // trigger lock, peek ahead to see if it is likely we would find
            // misfired triggers requiring recovery.
```

So this is quartz checking to see if any triggers have misfired since it last checked, so it can recover them.

This is default behaviour written straight into the engine, however you can control the second statement's frequency with this entry in your config file.

```
 <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
```